# AWS Backup for S3 buckets - what is the size limit?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, backup

I am using AWS Backup to back up S3 buckets. One of the buckets is about 190GB (the biggest of the buckets I am trying to back up) and it is the only bucket that the backup job fails on, with the error message:

```
Bucket [Bucket name] is too large, please contact AWS for support 
The backup job failed to create a recovery point for your resource [Bucket ARN] due to missing permissions on role [role ARN]
```

As you can see, these are two error messages concatenated together (probably an AWS bug) but I think that the second message is incorrect, because all the rest of the buckets were backed up successfully with the same permissions, and they are configured that same way. Thus, I think the first message is the issue.

I was wondering what is the size limit for AWS backup for S3. I took a look at the [AWS Backup quotas](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-backup/latest/devguide/aws-backup-limits.html) page and there was no mention of a size limit. How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the information you're looking for :
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-backup/latest/devguide/s3-backups.html#S3-backup-limitations

> Backup size limitations: AWS Backup for Amazon S3 allows you to
> automatically backup and restore S3 buckets up to 1 PB in size and
> containing fewer than 24 million objects.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the object count limit has been increased from 24 millions to

> S3 buckets require fewer than 3 billion objects in each bucket to be
> backed up.

[Link to AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-backup/latest/devguide/s3-backups.html)